# How widespread is the idiom 蘑菇?

Tags: mandarin, usage, characters, meaning-in-context, idioms

I have seen the word for mushroom [蘑菇, mógū] to be an action such as dilly dally.

Is this an inherent idiom in the written language apparent across a large spectrum of dialect, whereas the word mushroom connotes, from some reason such an action? Or is it local to spoken dialects of Manderin?

Comment: It is not called idiom, it is an expression,. Some Cantonese know this term  but never use it

Answer (score 4):

I heard it's being used especially by older people in northest region. For example, 别蘑菇了，老蘑菇什么.

It's a synonym of 磨蹭. Maybe, 蘑菇 sounds folksy.

You might find it's used in some old novels as well.

Comment: Saw it in Harry Potter!

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel It's interesting. Is it a Chinese version of Harry Potter?

Comment: Yes a translation.

Answer (score 1):

I was told it sounds like 东北话。I'm sure they just writ wrong!

There is:

磨蹭 or 磨叽， 磨磨叽叽 which have a meaning 'dawdle'.

zdic has:

比喻故意纠缠不清或拖延时间。

如：「别蘑菇，我忙得很。」也称为「摩姑」、「磨咕」